# What does the Datomic exception `read-transactor-location-failed` mean?

Tags: exception, datomic

I'm getting the following exception when deleting or creating a Datomic database (with Datomic Pro 0.9.4899):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: :db.error/read-transactor-location-failed Could not read transactor location from storage
    at datomic.error$arg.invoke(error.clj:55)
    at datomic.coordination$check_peer_version.invoke(coordination.clj:138)
    at datomic.coordination$lookup_compatible_transactor_endpoint.invoke(coordination.clj:149)
    at datomic.peer$send_admin_request$fn__8594.invoke(peer.clj:713)
    at datomic.peer$send_admin_request.invoke(peer.clj:707)
    at datomic.peer$delete_database.invoke(peer.clj:745)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at datomic.Peer.deleteDatabase(Peer.java:142)
    at datomic.api$delete_database.invoke(api.clj:23)
...
```

What does this exception mean? What are some common reasons it can occur?

Comment: Which storage are you using?

Comment: I'm using Amazon DynamoDB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When transactors launch, they write their location to storage. They actually write their location with every heartbeat message. If you see this message when a peer tries to connect, it means that either no transactor location has been written, or that they are otherwise unable to read from storage (and hit this error first in attempting to do so).

A cause for this for an AWS config -- say with AWS CloudFormation and DynamoDB as your storage -- would be launching with a transactor properties file that is not correctly configured to write to storage. When the peers attempt to connect to storage they won't be able to read the transactor's location. This could be because the transactor and peers are pointed at different storages. You could also run into permissions issues, e.g. the transactor does not have permissions to write to the storage you've specified (security groups config, etc.)

Either way, the general cause of this is what the error message says - that a transactor location can't be read from storage. It looks like the missing detail here is with how this happens when the system is healthy and correctly configured: that peers read the transactor location from storage and that the transactor writes its location as part of heartbeat (and on a failover event, the standby transactor will write its location when it takes over). There are various system configuration issues which might contribute to this.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: so how did you go about debugging this? I used the cloudformation template from https://github.com/vrivellino/clojure-west-2014-demo/blob/master/config/cfn-template.json and I'm seeing this error message now

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when I connect without the password in the database uri

```
datomic:dev://transactor:4334/mydb?password=XxXxXx
```

Answer (score 0):

*It's been a couple of weeks since I encountered this. I think I figured out the answer, but I'm not sure that I remember it correctly. So I'll make this a community wiki in case I'm wrong.*

The `:db.error/read-transactor-location-failed` means that there is not a valid backend storage service at the location configured in Datomic.

I encountered this error in AWS CloudFormation. I had both a transactor (running on an EC2 instance) and the backend storage (a DynamoDB table). I think this error occurred because the transactor started before the DynamoDB table was created. (Adding a `DependsOn` clause to the transactor instance fixed the problem.)

Comment: The "code", as such, is mainly an artifact of the name one chooses for the DynamoDB table, so it wouldn't make much sense to share the code here. Here's some more info on the `DependsOn` clause: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because the credentials that I had in my transactor file were wrong. Try changing your

```
sql-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/datomic
sql-user=datomic
sql-password=datomic
```

values to the correct ones that you used when creating postgres db, user, and tables.